# can I call methods from java application that use google cloud datastore in GAE without rewrite the code of connection to Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-datastore

I created java application (myLocalAPP) to connect and access google cloud datastore.
So, I use [Google cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs).
However, I'm now finding that I have to use *myLocalAPP* in a GAE app. (I export myLocalAPP to jar and add it to GAE /lib).

The problem is that GAE has different API to connect to Google datastore and the connection,insert and retrieve methods that I've created them in myLocalAPP aren't working when I call them from GAE application. 
I got exception such:

```
java.lang.Error:  compilation problems: 
The method beginTransaction(TransactionOptions) in the type DatastoreService is not applicable for the arguments (DatastoreV1.BeginTransactionRequest)
The method lookup(DatastoreV1.LookupRequest) is undefined for the type DatastoreService
Entity.Builder cannot be resolved to a type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from DatastoreV1.Entity to Entity
```

So, I go back to myLocalAPP and try to change the connection method. I change the datastore object from

```
Datastore datastore = DatastoreFactory.get().create(DatastoreHelper.getOptionsfromEnv()
          .dataset(datasetId).build());
```

to

```
Datastore datastore = (Datastore )DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
```

but casting does not work. I need to use *DatastoreService* object and I have to rewrite the other methods.  I would like to know is there any way other than rewriting the code?? and if I rewrite the code using GAE datastore API, is myLocalAPP will work again locally?? (not on GAE).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The client library for communicating with Google Cloud Datastore is not currently compatible with the API used by App Engine Datastore.

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/34) on the Google Cloud Datastore issue tracker to enhance the App Engine Java client library to work on top of Cloud Datastore (this would also enable the use of higher-level libraries like Objectify). You can subscribe to that issue to receive updates.